# SystemExtr quit unexpectedly

Tags: macos, imac, crash

[image]
This message keeps on popping up again and again. I tried restarting my Mac and did no good. I thought it was steam causing these problems but deleting it did not make any difference.

Do you think this is a problem with MacOS Mojave? Please help me.

Comment: open the report and look where it says "process responsible .... it should be about 10-20 lines down

Comment: can you find that process `SystemExtr` in the Activity Monitor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not a problem with macOS Mojave. I've seen this before and it was caused by an app hiding within the Library folder.

Unfortunately I don't recall the app, but I do recall how we got to the bottom of it. In summary:

1. Install [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) (it's free from the Mac App Store)
2. Search for SystemExtr
3. Identify the file (app) responsible
4. Remove it

As mentioned, from memory it was sitting in the Library folder.

<sup>**NOTE:** I am in no way affiliated with EasyFind.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

if you click on the report button you will see the location of SystemExtr. I had also the same problem and mine was located under `~/Library/SystemExtr` so I removed the whole folder and it stopped to show up anymore.

Comment: what is it ? what app/process uses it ? I do not have it on High Sierra.

Comment: I don't know to be honest, I found this [link](https://forums.macg.co/threads/systemextr-a-quitte-de-maniere-imprevue.1311293/#post-13362908) and they think it is a malware.. although I cannot say. I think it is a new thing, so better keep an eye on the news in near future as it might be something else remaining on the system as well...